# Android update arrayadapter data from a background Service

Tags: android, service, android-arrayadapter

I have a Service running in background with a timed event. Every 5 minutes I want to download a new list of data and update an arrayadapter (used for an AutoComplete Textview box in the main Activity). How do i do this? Or if this is not doable from a Service?

I tried making the textView public static and setting an adapter directly but the program crashes saying that line cannot be done from a "thread that did not call Looper.prepare"

Thanks.

Comment: you should add some code stuff that how are you trying it.

Comment: @James Gu - Look at my answer, Hope you will get your works from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because you are trying to update the UI from a NON-UI thread. Try to use `runOnUiThread()`, put the stuff to update the UI inside the `runOnUiThread()`.

**UPDATE**

If you are updating in service you should use the context instead of Activity_name.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // here you can add stuff to Update the UI.
            }
        });
```

Comment: check my updated answer and add some code to let me know what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy list is the sample app.i think if you make use of async class

http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/

Your life could be better